# connect Crystal Reports with JDBC to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, connection, jdbc, crystalreports

I want to connect Crystal Reports (2016, Support Pack 8, version 14.2.8.3426)     to a PostgreSQL 12 database. Using JDBC. The database is on my local computer, on port 5433. My database name: ogc   which is in public schema.

I have downloaded the driver:

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.2.12.jar

I extracted the driver.

I changed the CRconfig to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\java/lib/postgresql-42.2.12.jar;${CLASSPATH}

I can connect to the database using:

jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/ogc

my database class:  org.postgresql.Driver

So far so good.

[In data explorer I get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8ghm.png)

So, the connection is there.
However, when I want to select tables to use in the report, I get the error:

Retrieving data from the the database has failed. Details: not implemented.

What am I missing, to use the tables I want?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it; my postgres db has the PostGIS extension, and the tables a geom field. 
The driver does not handle that.

So I copied the table and deleted the geom field.